# Running Total giving errors in SSRS. Query works fine out of SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am making a report that shows the monthly reduction in inventory.   500 in the query is that start number.   I am using an Oracle datasource.  Query runs fine in oracle and gives the desired results including the running total.  I put it in SSRS and all results are correct except I get errors on the running total.  Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ISSUED1, 'MM'), COUNT(*), (500-SUM(COUNT(*))  OVER  (ORDER BY 
TO_CHAR(ISSUED1, 'MM') RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) 
AS 
RUNNING_TOTAL
FROM TEST.INVENTORY
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ISSUED1, 'MM')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(ISSUED1,'MM')
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error comes from the runing total? Try to assign names (aliases) to the other fields.

Comment: Thank you for the response. While I've been wrong in the past I am pretty sure.  The other columns in SSRS produce the proper results and the running total show column shows #Error

Comment: Maybe you can let us know the error message and when exactly the error occurs. Also: How did SSRS name the first two fields?

Comment: it runs the query sucessfull just dispals #Error for running total.  Exporting it to Excel give #VALUE! for that column

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by changing "interpret subtotals as detail rows" to false under DataSet Properties...Options...Subtotals.  Thank you wolfgang for our efforts.